# Is import static a good practice?

Tags: java, import, static

I was asking my self while coding in Java, does the `import static com.example.method` is a good the to do or is it better to import the whole class.

Comment: In this case I think importing the whole class is more normal.  But I wouldn't say importing a static method is automatically bad.

Comment: I restrict myself to import statics to enums (especially when extensively used in the class) and methods when they are used functional parameters (ie Class.staticComparator());

Comment: I used to be a big fan of static imports years ago, but now I have banned it everywhere I can, even for `Assertions.*` or `Mockito.*`. The rationale behind this is that not all names are good for static imports (e.g., `of`, `forName`, `valueOf`); importing a single class does not cause (much) (git) diff when adding/removing many static imports; static imports may clash and may look ambiguous (e.g. `getInstance`, `valueOf`). Class-prefixed names _retain_ context (e.g. compare: `SECOND` - is it an enum-value from `TimeUnit` or does it come as a constant from somewhere else?)

Comment: @fluffy Context matters greatly. A number of DSLs, for example, are built to be easily readable when statically imported.

Comment: Another pro for not using static imports, but now as a personal preference only, is that I have a rich-color syntax highlighting scheme, so that types (but distinctly for classes, interfaces, abstract classes and enums) are recognized as a sort of colorful context marker in order not to be confused with a (static) member of the calling class or a statically imported member (I would think that my IDE would have to provide an option to highlight static imports, but this is how I keep readability for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the context, not exist an explicit rule to use in all the cases. But the most common use is when you do a test and need to import classes like **Assert.*** or **Mockito.***, in order to no-repeat **Assertion.assertEquals** a lot of times a good idea is to do something like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class ErrorsControllerImplTest {

    @Test
    void should_return_all_the_errors_types() {
        ErrorsController controller = new ErrorsControllerImpl();

        assertAll(
                () -> assertEquals(58, controller.getAllErrors().size()),
                () -> assertEquals("BadRequestStatus {code=4000509, message='Site must have a value'}",
                        controller.getAllErrors().get(0)));
    }
}
```

As another user said, the idea is that the code will be readable and remove duplicates parts.

Comment: well, you do have a point in here. +1.  It would indeed be useful here. Anyway I still hate it, is devil.

Comment: I agree with you, I don't like to use it. The only place where I use this type of imports is in the Unit Test, in the rest of the classes I prefer to understand what is this static method.