# Call method in java without object or class name

Tags: java, android-studio

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id. my_button)
```

As much I know in java all code have to be on a class body, that said if we invoke a method we must have to call it through object or if it's a static method then through its class name like `bla.findViewByID(somemoreblass)`

But in android studio I see this `Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id. my_button)`

Can anyone explain how it works?

Comment: `findViewById` is a static method of the class where `mybutton` is declared or it's import static

Comment: that's a cool username

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452714/is-import-static-a-good-practice

Comment: @aran I think so

Comment: @fantaghirocco did you mean it's a static method of class
Button class? Sorry I'm on rn so can't highlight Button as code

Answer (score 2):

`findViewById()` is a method in the `Activity` class from which you are extending given you are in an `Activity`. Just like any method which is defined within a class or parent class, this method can be called without using a class name or reference.